# Rings whose finitely-generated modules are co-hopfian

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Let $A$ be a unital, possibly noncommutative ring. Dischinger showed [1] that the following are equivalent:

1. For every $a \in A$, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $a^n A = a^{n+1} A$;
2. For every $a \in A$, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $A a^n = A a^{n+1}$;
3. Every cyclic right module $M \in Mod_A$ is co-hopfian (i.e. every injective endomorphism of $M$ is an isomorphism);
4. Every cyclic left module $M \in {}_A Mod$ is co-hopfian.

Such a ring $A$ is called *strongly $\pi$-regular*. Every strongly $\pi$-regular ring $A$ is *$\pi$-regular* in the sense that for every $a \in A$ there is some $n \geq 1$ such that $a^n$ is a von Neumann regular element of $A$ (i.e. $a^n = a^n b a^n$ for some $b \in A$).  <strike>Every von Neumann regular ring is strongly $\pi$-regular,</strike> and if $A$ is commutative, then $A$ is strongly $\pi$-regular iff $A/nil(A)$ is von Neumann regular.

Dischinger also showed that the following are equivalent:

1. Every finitely-generated right module $M \in Mod_A$ is co-hopfian;
2. Every finitely-generated left module $M \in {}_A Mod$ is co-hopfian;
3. Every finite-rank matrix ring over $A$ is strongly $\pi$-regular;
4. Every ring right (or left) Morita equivalent to $A$ is strongly $\pi$-regular.

Let's call such a ring $A$ *very strongly $\pi$-regular*.  <strike>Every von Neumann regular ring is very strongly $\pi$-regular.</strike>

**Questions:**

1. Is there a direct ring-theoretic, rather than module-theoretic, characterization of very strongly $\pi$-regular rings which doesn't explicitly mention matrix rings?
2. What is an example of a very strongly $\pi$-regular ring $A$ such that $A$ is not von Neumann regular but the center $Z(A)$ is von Neumann regular?

[1] Dischinger, Friedrich. “Sur Les Anneaux Fortement π-Réguliers.” CR Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. AB 283, no. 8 (1976): 571–573. [link](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k62355157/f583.item.r=dischinger).

Comment: (2) Let $M$ be the monoid $\{1,x,y\}$ with $xy=xx=x$, $yx=yy=y$ and unit $1$. Let $K$ a field, and $A=KM$. Then the center of $A$ is reduced to $K$ (so is von Neumann regular). $A$ itself is not von Neumann regular because $x-y\notin (x-y)A(x-y)=0$. But since $A$ is a finite-dimensional $K$-algebra, clearly every finitely generated left $A$-module is cohopfian.

Comment: The algebra suggested by @YCor is isomorphic to 2x2 upper triangular matrices over K which obviously has the desired properties since it has a non-trivial Jacobson radical the strictly upper triangular matrices

Comment: In general the path algebra of a finite connected acyclic quiver with at least one edge over K has center K and is not von Neumann regular but is strongly $\pi$-regular.

Comment: Just would like to +1 Benjamin's comment: von Neumann regular does not imply strongly $\pi$-regular. A *strongly (von Neumann) regular* ring is strongly $\pi$-regular, and a von Neumann regular ring is $\pi$-regular.  Here are [a few other examples](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=14&L=45) of VNR rings that aren't strongly $\pi$-regular.

Comment: Since "strong von Neumann regularity" isn't Morita invariant, it would not be possible to use it as a replacement as an example of "very strong $\pi$-regularity"

Comment: @rschwieb Wow, DaRT looks awesome! I wish it had "pure semisimple" and "finite representation type", but what it has so far is quite impressive!

Comment: @TimCampion I’m open to adding new conditions, especially when you can help provide interconnections between conditions and good papers for sources. Register and use a submission form and we can talk about it :)